# Separating values of a column in a CSV in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, csv

I have multiple files contain a persons Fullname in a single cell. I would like to separate these names into two columns - first name and Surname

the code I have used to separate values worked in a previous iteration of the script I had but now no longer works

I can't pinpoint where the error lies, can anyone advise?

```
$path          = 'C:\MAY2019correct'

#XYZ

$excelOut      = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'XYZ.csv'
$completedFile = Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'Completed-XYZ.csv'
$defaultValue  = 'ABC'
$filter        = '*XYZ*'
$excelFile     = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter $filter -File | 
Select-Object -First 1
$allstaff = @()

if ($excelFile) {
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application -Property @{Visible = 
$false} 
# Open the file
$workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile.FullName) 
# Activate the first worksheet
$sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Item(1) 
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the first row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 2 row
[void]$sheet.Cells.Item(1, 1).EntireRow.Delete() # Delete the 3 row

$workbook.SaveAs($excelOut,6)
# Close workbook and save changes
$workbook.Close($true) 
# Quit Excel
$excel.Quit()

# clean-up Com objects
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($sheet) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($workbook) | Out-Null
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excel) | Out-Null

$headers = 'Element Name','Surname','EmployeeNo','Amount','YTD'
# import the csv file and select all the above headers plus one that is created using a calculated property
$csv = Import-Csv -Path $excelOut -Header $headers -UseCulture | Select-Object *, @{Name = 'Paycentre'; Expression = {$defaultValue}}|


Write-Host "Creating completed csv file '$completedFile'"
$csv | Export-Csv -Path $completedFile -UseCulture -Force - 
NoTypeInformation
}
else {
Write-Warning "Could not find a file using filter '$filter' in path 
'$path'"
}

foreach($staff in $completedFile)
{

   #Get the values from the CSV for this row
   $Surname = $staff.Surname
   $Surname = $Surname.Substring(0, $Surname.lastIndexOf(' '))
   $Initial = $staff.Surname
   $Initial = $Initial.Substring($Initial.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1 )
   $Firstname = $staff.Surname
   $Firstname = $Firstname.Substring($Initial.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1 )
   $EmployeeNo = $staff.EmployeeNo
   $NINumber = $staff.NINumber
   $Amount = $staff.Amount
   $Paycentre = $staff.Paycentre

   $staff2  = New-Object System.Object
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Surname" -Value $Surname
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FirstName" -Value $Firstname
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "EmployeeNo" -Value $EmployeeNo
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NINumber" -Value $NINumber
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Amount" -Value $Amount
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "FirstName" -Value $Initial
   $staff2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Paycentre" -Value $Paycentre
   #add to array
    $allstaff += $staff2
 } 

 $allstaff | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $completedFile
```

Comment: Where does `NINumber` come from? It is not in the csv you are creating from the Excel, plus I don't see what the fields `Element Name` and `YTD` are used for. Don't create headers in the csv where afterwards you are using completely different names for these fields. Also, in your creation of `$staff2` you are defining the property `FirstName` twice AND you are iterating a file path `$completedFile` (string) instead of the actual data which is in `$csv`. Another thing is that you seem to breah code lines at random places with newlines.

Comment: Hi @Theo there is a limitation in Stack overflow that will not let me ✓ until i have avieved 15 reputation - the second I do, I will. 

As for the field information these are titles that are applied after i receive information in varios formats, I get xlsx, csv, txt. docs that all need to run through the script.

we apply the headers and then use headers to extract relevant information we want/can use for our master doc. not all of the files received have the same information or event complete information for all rows.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is that your `foreach` loop is iterating over the `$completedFile` variable which appears to be a file path, not a collection.

Should it be `foreach ($staff in $csv)` instead?

Also, be very wary of dealing with names in code. It's super easy to make poor assumptions that break things. See [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://shinesolutions.com/2018/01/08/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names-with-examples/) for more info there.